# Proving homomorphism from a cyclic group of prime order to some other group is injective or trivial

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Here's my attempt:

I'll be using this for my proof:

> If $\varphi : G \to G^\prime $ is a group homomorphism and $a \in G$
>   with $\text{ord} (a) = r$ then $\text{ord} (\varphi (a))$ divides $r$.

Let $G=\langle a \rangle$ where $\text{ord} (a) = p$ for some prime $p$ and $G^{\prime }$ be any other group. Also it is easy to notice if $\varphi$ is any homomorphism from $G$ to $G^{\prime }$ then $\varphi$ is determined by $\varphi (a)$. (In other words, to define the homomorphism we only need to define $\varphi (a)$.

Now if $\varphi (a) = e_{G^{\prime}}$ then for any $n \in \mathbb{Z}_p$, we have $\varphi (a^n)= (\varphi (a)) ^n = e_{G^{\prime}}$. Thus making $\varphi$ the trivial homomorphism. Now, suppose that $\varphi (a) \ne e_{G^{\prime}}$ then we need to show $\varphi$ is injective. Let $x,y \in G$. Then  $x=a^m$ and $y=a^n$ for some $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}_p$. If $\varphi (x) = \varphi (y)$ then $\varphi (a^m ) = \varphi (a^n )$. It follows that $(\varphi (a))^{m-n} = e_{G^{\prime}}$. Now, by the corollary at the beginning of the proof, we must have that $\text{ord} (\varphi (a))$ divides $p$. Thus, it must be that $\text{ord} (\varphi (a)) = p$. And if  $(\varphi (a))^{m-n} = e_{G^{\prime}}$ then $p$ divides $m-n$ but $m-n < p$ (since $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}_p$) thus it must be that $m=n$. And therefore, $x=y$ and thus $\varphi$ is injective.

Is my proof correct? Or am I missing out something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct, but if you know the right notions it can be shortened as follows: the kernel $K$ of $\varphi$ is a subgroup of $G$, hence it is also cyclic, and by Lagrange's Theorem its order divides the order of $G$. Hence it must be either $p$, in which case $K=G$ and $\varphi$ is trivial, or $1$, in which case $K=\{e\}$ and $\varphi$ is injective.

But this is really the same thing as your argument : the fact you used is the combination of Lagrange and the fact that subgroups of cyclic groups are cyclic, and your use of $m-n$ is pretty much the same thing as the standard argument to reduce injectivity to the kernel being trivial.

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is correct.

Let me offer another approach: If $\phi:G\to G'$ is a homomorphism, then $\ker(\phi)\lhd G$ is a subgroup. The only subgroups of $G$ are $G$ itself and $\langle e_G\rangle$. If $\ker(\phi)=G$, then $\phi$ is trivial. If $\ker(\phi)=\langle e_G\rangle$, then $\phi$ is injective.

Comment: I wouldn't call this another approach; if you unpack everything you will get pretty much the same proof.

Comment: Shouldn't $\phi$ be injective instead of be isomorphic if $\text{ker} \phi = {e_G}$

Comment: @AshishK yes, I meant injective.

Comment: @ArnaudD. You are welcome to quibble with my wording. I would describe "referring to standard facts" as a different approach than "reproving standard facts". But, I'm not interested in getting into it with you.

Comment: I just thought it was interesting to note that Ashish K's arguments were actually quite similar to the other proof, as I was not sure Ashish knew all these facts. My comment was certainly not meant to criticize your answer, and I am sincerely sorry if you took it that way (I probably could have made my point clearer).